# Missing required parameter "property" - Google Analytics Data API error

Tags: google-analytics-api

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Replace the values in the following line with your own credentials
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(r"C:\Users\xxxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.json")

# Create a Google Analytics Data API client
analytics_service = build('analyticsdata', 'v1beta', credentials=creds)

# Define the Google Analytics Data API request for a GA4 property
request = {
  'property': 'properties/xxxxx',
  'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
  'dimensions': [{'name': 'date'}],
  'metrics': [{'name': 'activeUsers'}]
}

# Call the Google Analytics Data API using the request
try:
    response = analytics_service.properties().runReport(body={'request': request}).execute()
    # Print the response
    print(response)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I've given the service account appropriate access to Google Analytics 4's admin and on IAM. I've also activated the Google Analytics Data API on GCP but I keep getting the below error,

**Missing required parameter "property"**

I was expecting to pull data from the property ID I had entered

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Define the Google Analytics Data API request for a GA4 property
# Here is where it went right for me
request = {
  'property': 'properties/xxxxx',
  'requestBody': {
    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
    'dimensions': [{'name': 'date'}],
    'metrics': [{'name': 'activeUsers'}]
  }
}
```